# DynamoDB only saving one record from JSON list

Tags: javascript, node.js, amazon-dynamodb

I'm trying to loop through a list of URLs in a JSON file, call an API and then save the results in the database. It loops through the whole list but only saves the first URL results. How can I get all URLs in the loop to be saved after each API call?

My code:

```
exports.putItemHandler = async (event) => {
const { body, httpMethod, path } = event;
if (httpMethod !== 'POST') {
    throw new Error(`postMethod only accepts POST method, you tried: ${httpMethod} method.`);
}
// All log statements are written to CloudWatch by default. For more information, see
// https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/nodejs-prog-model-logging.html
console.log('received:', JSON.stringify(event));

console.log('----STARTING LOOP----')
console.log(v4())
console.log(urls)

var _id;


try {
    
    for (const url of urls) {

        _id = v4();

        const resp = await axios.get(endpoint, {
            params: {
                key: API_KEY,
                url: url
            }
        });

        console.log(JSON.stringify(resp.data))

        const lighthouseResults = resp.data;        

        const params = {
            TableName: tableName,
            Item: { id: _id,
                    created_at: new Date().toISOString(),
                    URL: url,
                    fullJson: lighthouseResults,
                },
        };
        await docClient.put(params).promise();
    
        const response = {
            statusCode: 200,
            body,
        };
    
        console.log(`response from: ${path} statusCode: ${response.statusCode} body: ${response.body}`);
        return response;

    }
} catch (err) {
   console.error(err)
}
};
```

Comment: You placed a return statement in your `for of` loop.  Move `return response` outside the loop.

Comment: @fedonev it's already outside the loop

Comment: not according to the code you posted. Its clearly inside the same brackets as the for loop.  Just pasted your code into vsCode and collapsing the for loop catches the return statement